# invalid command name "zlib" while executing http::geturl

Tags: http-headers, tcl, zlib

I'm on TCL 8.5 (can't upgrade) and running version 2.7.7 of the HTTP package. I'm calling a library which appears to be using the following http::geturl command to download an image which has been gzipped:

```
http::geturl $url -headers {Accept-Encoding gzip}
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
invalid command name "zlib"
```

Searching on the web, I could only find this reference to the bug which basically recommends stopping sending Accept-Encoding gzip, which I can't do (nor can I upgrade to 8.6) http://sourceforge.net/p/tcl/bugs/4784/

My question is: is there any 8.5 workaround for this issue? Is there a way to stop this library from sending the "Accept-Encoding gzip" header?

Comment: `http::geturl -headers {Accept-Encoding {}}`?

Comment: Thanks but I can't change the actual http::geturl call itself. I thought there might be a way to over-ride the header somehow.

Comment: You can. Either edit the http lib (it is written in Tcl) or provide a noop zlib or replace `http::geturl` with a wrapper at runtime.

Comment: What would a "noop zlib" look like? Sounds like a good way to go.

Comment: `proc zlib args {lindex $args end}`

Comment: That gives this error: can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&". Any suggestions @JohannesKuhn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code believes you've got the zlib package (which supplies the `zlib` command) available, and so turns on support for gzip-compressed streams. The simplest fix in your code is to do:

```
package require zlib
```

So long as this happens before you call into the code that does the `http::geturl`, this should be enough.

If you don't have the package (in which case you'll get a clear failure from the `package require`) then you've hit a bug either where the soft dependency code in the http package is getting it wrong when building the request headers, or in the server which is sending gzipped data despite not being asked for it. The code pointed to from [TIP #234](http://tip.tcl.tk/234) (i.e., the SVN repository at http://svn.scheffers.net/zlib) contains the source for a version of the zlib package, in particular it's the version that formed the starting point for the built-in support in Tcl 8.6, but I think it only uses Tcl 8.5 APIs.

<sup>Unhelpfully, there are several versions of the zlib package around; this is one of the messiest Tcl packages to acquire, alas.</sup>

Comment: Thank you Donal. That explains some of my confusion, as when I tried "teacup install zlib", it suggested a package called zlibtcl. So naturally I assumed that was the correct name. When that didn't work, I turned here for help. I'll make an attempt to install the version of zlib you've linked to here.

Comment: By the way, I checked the server response with Fiddler, and it only gzips the image when explicitly sent the "Accept-Encoding gzip" header. So as you state, the problem may arise in the http package when sending the request.

Comment: Hi Donal, that Scheffers link you gave isn't working. Do you have an alternative source for the package, by any chance? I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @user2740842 Alas, the only other place I've got is the Tcl 8.6 sources themselves (which I've written a fair chunk of, based on the link I gave you and subsequently hacked around), and they're not really designed for separate building. Still, they might be extractable; the code isn't _too_ tight with the rest.

Comment: And it was precisely this awkwardness with getting a known copy of the sources which was one of the reasons it got put in 8.6. (Another reason was that it enabled some critical functionality downstream, such as proper HTTP/1.1 and built-in PNG image support in Tk.)